# Export/Import of user data from an oracle remote database with java

Tags: java, oracle, import, remote-access, database-backups

I'm trying to realize a backup/export and restore/import of the data of an oracle database user under some specific requirements. I already have a solution in mind but would be pleased about feedback if it's the right way.

On the client, there is running a Java application with access to a remote oracle database via jdbc. It's also possible to run `sql*plus` via ProcessBuilder at the client. The client should need a minimum of rights. On the server, there is running Oracle Database 10 (or higher).

The goal is
a) to export the data of this application/user only (and later)
b) to import the data to an other remote database
without having file access to the remote database server (no ssh, ftp, Enterprise Manager; only via jdbc, sql*plus or other client tools), and the database instance should not create data on the server because the client is not able to delete the files. A direct copy/duplication of the data to another database without intermediate files is not intended.

### My approach

#### Export

i) creating the table definition files (tableName.sql) via sql*plus:

```
spool tableName.sql
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','tableName','dbUser') from dual;
spool off;
```

ii) extract the data of every table of the user to flatfiles (tableName.txt) via sqlplus and appropriate variables (linesize and so on):

```
spool tableName.txt;
select * from tableName;
spool off;
```

#### Import

i) run the generated sql scripts to create the tables

ii) run sql*Loader in order to import the table data:

```
sqlldr dbUser/dbPW control=loadTable.control
```

where loadTable.control is:

```
load data
infile 'tableName.txt'
into table tableName
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( ... )
```

At the moment I have some problems with the formatting of the tableName.txt and ***asking myself if there is an alternative approach***. Additionly I think I will have some problems with the charsets of client/server too.

If I have understood correctly, the Data Pump Export/Import tool requires a DATABASE LINK and therefore an oracle instance running on the client.

I think RMAN needs too much rights and is focused on backing up the whole database.

### Some background information

I have realized the same procedure for a MySQL database already. I implemented the export as follows:
i) creating the table definition files (tableName.sql) via `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for every table
ii) extract the data of every table to files (tableName.txt) via

```
mysql --host=dbHost --port=dbPort --user=dbUser --password=dbPassword --default-character-set=DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET --quick --database=dbName --execute='Select * from table' > tableName.txt
```

For the import I run the generated sql scripts to create the tables followed by the execution of

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'tablename.txt' REPLACE INTO TABLE tableName;
```

Comment: You could still use `exp`/`imp`; although they're desupported I think I'd prefer that to rolling my own solution. Has that option ben discounted? And has the possibility of creating an instance on the client just for the DB link been completely ruled out? And SQL Developer has an export function - I haven't used it but I think it can do this.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have only read that exp/imp is not recommended for Oracle10 or higher because some features are not supported. Therefore I have only looked into the Data Pump.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, creating an instance on the client should be avoided.
The favoured solution would be to have a minimum of requirements (ideally only java and jdbc). To use sql*plus and sql*loader is already a loss.

Comment: Data pump is certainly the supported tool and is more flexible, so I'd always recommend that over `exp`/`imp`. But unless you plan to implement those features in your Java code that may be a moot point in this case. If your DB doesn't have anything that `exp` can't handle, is it worth the risk of writing your own version? Only you can decide that of course.

Comment: I have to check if there is something that `exp` can't handle and if these restrictions are acceptable. Maybe I have to rethink the decision to disregard exp/imp. Thanks for your advice!